# How do you get an object from an array of JavaScript dicts by key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, ejs

I hope I'm using the right terminology...I'm usually a Python guy, so I'm used to the dictionary datatype. Anyway, I'm working on a Node app right now, and I've run into a problem. I'm having users select from a dropdown menu, which is populated via an array of dictionary objects passed into EJS. Each object has a slug, and a name. So, it would be something like this:

```
const computers = [{slug: 'dell-desktop', name: 'Dell Desktop'}, {slug: 'macbook-pro', name: 'MacBook Pro'}, {slug: 'imac-27-inch', name: 'iMac, 27-Inch'}];
```

I populate the form using the names, but I will need the slugs for URL stuff in the backend. So it looks like this:

```
app.get('/form', function(req, res){
res.render('form.ejs', {computers: computers});
});
```

Everything seems to work beautifully in general, with the form populating as expected:

```
<select id = 'computer' name = 'computer'>
        <% for (var i = 0; i<computers.length; i++) { %>
          <option value = '<%= computers[i].slug %>'><%= computers[i].name %></option>
          <% } %>
        </select>
```

However, the data that I receive from the form just provides the slug. My question is, is there a good way to use the slug key to then get the name from the array of dictionaries? I've tried like this, but it's not working, and I wonder if it's because they're in an array?

```
app.post('/form', function(req, res){
  var c_slug = req.body.computer;
  var name = computers[c_slug];
  console.log(c_slug);
  console.log(name);
  res.send('Success!')
});
```

I haven't been able to find anything specific to this in my searches. I've found a mapping explanation, but that gets all of the values for a given key. I'm hoping there's just something obvious I'm missing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method to find the element in array which matches given criteria.

> It returns the **value** of the **first element** in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise, `undefined` is returned.

```
app.post('/form', function(req, res){
  const c_slug = req.body.computers;
  const element = computers.find(el => el.slug === c_slug);
  // element is either an element that was found or undefined
  if (element) {
     const name = element.name;
     // the above can be written like this in ES6
     // const { name } = element;

     // do something
  } else {
     // return 400 (Bad Request)
  }
...
```

*P.S.* I'm using [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) instead of `var` which is [ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_2015_support_in_Mozilla) syntax and [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) `() => ...`. Both are available on server-side in NodeJS 8+.

Answer (score 0):

you can use .find() method

```
app.post('/form', function(req, res){
  var c_slug = req.body.computers;
  var computer = computers.find(el => el.slug === c_slug);
  console.log(c_slug);
  console.log(computer.name);
  res.send('Success!')
});
```

or you can find it manually

```
app.post('/form', function(req, res){
  var c_slug = req.body.computers;
  var name ;   
  for (let i = 0; i < computers.length; i++) {
    if (computers[i]['slug'] === c_slug) {
      name = computers[i]['slug'];
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log(c_slug);
  console.log(name);
  res.send('Success!')
});
```